# Custom coded configurator on Cpanel Subdomain for existing Shopify marketplace

Tags: server, shopify, cpanel, cname

a. I have a Shopify shop ex: shop.com 
b. The product configurator is a PHP built and its hosted on a server (https://zaorstudiofurniture.com/index.php?page=configurator)
c. How can I setup configurator.shop.com URL if my domain is hosted on Shopify?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run PHP code on Shopify. You can however set your DNS up so that your configurator App runs as a subdomain on zaorstudiofurniture.com. For example, you would run your shopify store as:

```
www.zaorstudiofurniture.com
```

and your configurator as:

```
config.zaorstudiofurniture.com
```

with simple DNS settings. Shopify has some DNS settings internal to their admin that is good for ensuring Shopify stores run on domains correctly, but no one really needs that unless they are total n00bs to Internet. Setting up your own DNS ensures you can run your PHP, your Shopify, email and any other services without too much trouble.